# Windows 11 Keeps Changing Documents & Pictures folders to OneDrive Folder

Tags: windows-11

I already force changed the location, but once again it swapped it back to the onedrive folder. Basically instead of being folders under the user, they are put into subfolders inside a onedrive folder.

Any way I can completely and permanently get rid of any onedrive bs from my computer?

For clarity, I am trying to:

1. Change my documents/pictures location to be the default (C/users/user/xxxx) instead of (C/users/user/onedrive/xxxx)
2. Stop windows from changing it back
3. Delete anything else related to onedrive that may be related to this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you disable the Desktop synchronizing from within Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the registry.

Run regedit

Go here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

edit this stuff:

```
Desktop - %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
Favorites - %USERPROFILE%\Favorites
Music - %USERPROFILE%\Music
Pictures - %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
Videos - %USERPROFILE%\Videos
Documents - %USERPROFILE%\Documents
Downloads - %USERPROFILE%\Downloads
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.